# Summarize Django Queryset where Amount falls into Specific Groups

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'd like to group my transactions by the amount category that they fall into and sum those. I'd love to do this with 1 query, but I can't figure out what this kind of grouping is called. So I'm having a hard time finding any examples.

```
zero_to_twenty = Transactions.objects.filter(amount__lte=0, amount__gt=-20).aggregate(Sum("amount"))
twenty_to_fifty = Transactions.objects.filter(amount__lte=-20, amount__gt=-50).aggregate(Sum("amount"))
fifty_to_seventy_five = Transactions.objects.filter(amount__lte=-50, amount__gt=-75).aggregate(Sum("amount"))
seventy_five_to_one_hundred = Transactions.objects.filter(amount__lte=-75, amount__gt=-100).aggregate(
    Sum("amount")
)
one_hundred_plus = Transactions.objects.filter(amount__lte=-100).aggregate(Sum("amount"))
```

Obviously this is not ideal, but it gets me the correct data. Is it possible to do this with 1 query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try to group `Transactions` into groups and then run a `Sum` for those groups.

```py
Transactions.objects.filter(amount__lte=0).annotate(
    group=Case(
        When(Q(amount__lte=0, amount__gt=-20), then=Value("above_minus_20")),
        When(Q(amount__lte=-20, amount__gt=-50), then=Value("between_minus_20_minus_50")),
        When(Q(amount__lte=-50, amount__gt=-75), then=Value("between_minus_50_minues_75")),
        When(Q(amount__lte=-75, amount__gt=-100), then=Value("between_minus_75_minues_100")),
        When(Q(amount__lte=-100), then=Value("below_minues_100")),
        default=Value("no_group"),
    ),
).annotate(sum_group_amount=Window(expression=Sum("amount"), partition_by="group")).values(
    "group", "sum_group_amount"
).distinct()
```

It should return something along this lines

```py
<QuerySet [
    {'group': 'above_minus_20', 'sum_group_amount': Decimal('1111.20')}, 
    {'group': 'between_minus_20_minus_50', 'sum_group_amount': Decimal('120.22')}
    ...
]>
```

Comment: Ah. `Case` is what I was looking for. Late night coding and my brain wasn't working. I'll test this out.